# vue.js updating different model from form select

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js

I've got a dynamic select list created with `vue.js`. I want to update a "details" box on the page with data grabbed via an `ajax` call. The basic idea is here: https://jsfiddle.net/pznej8dz/1/

I don't see why the `sf_detail` data isn't being updated when the object is updated from the webservice call. Is there a different way this should be done in vue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object references are getting out of sync! Calling `getSourceFieldDetails` causes `field` and `sf_detail` to reference different objects.

## The Problem

At the start of the script, an object is created

```
{
  Name: 'Test',
  Label: 'Data',
  Type: 'Boolean'
};
```

And that object is given a reference named `sf_detail`.

In `sf_detail_info`, `field` is set equal to the reference named `sf_detail`

```
data: {
  field: sf_detail
}
```

But, in `getSourceFieldDetails`, `sf_detail` is set to reference a *new object*. Thus `sf_detail` references the new object, but `field` still references the old one.

### The Solution

The simplest solution is to never set `sf_detail` equal to a new object. Instead, update the properties of the existing object. The modified version of `getSourceFieldDetails` looks like this:

```
function getSourceFieldDetails(val) {
  // this would actually call an ajax endpoint to get this data
  console.log(val[0]);
  sf_detail.Name = val[0];
  sf_detail.Label = val[0] + 'Label',
  sf_detail.Type = val[0] + 'DataType'
  console.dir(sf_detail);
}
```

[Here is a fork of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asemahle/j4mw5mqb/) with the change.